# How to add hyperlink in jquery replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script and I want to replace `barbel` with `a href`

```
$(".text_div, p").text(function() {
  return $(this).text().replace("barbel", '<a href="#">mpara</a>');
});

$(".text_div").text(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace("some", "red");  
});
```

Comment: Write `<a href=""'>ancher text</a>` in second parameter of `.replace()`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where is that `href` that you are trying to replace "barbel" with? How is this not working?

Comment: A few hours ago, you asked similar question, if you go like this, you may have question ban. Be careful!

Comment: yeah but i made a mistake. i want the href instead of mpara

Comment: @Bakar So you should update previous question. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues here:

- Use `html()`, not `text()`, to insert HTML in to the DOM.
- Be careful with your quotes as you're causing a syntax error by mis-matching them.
- Use the second argument of the handler function to receive the current HTML value of the element instead of creating another jQuery object by accessing the DOM again.

With all that said, try this:

```
$(".text_div, p").html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace('barbel', '<a href="#">mpara</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
console.log('Before:');
console.log($('.content').html());


$(".text_div ,p").each((index, elem) => {
  let newHtml = $(elem).html().replace('barbel', '<a href="#">mpara</a>');
  $(elem).html(newHtml);
});
$(".text_div").each((index, elem) => {
  let newHtml = $(elem).html().replace('some', "red");
  $(elem).html(newHtml);
});

console.log('\n\nAfter:');
console.log($('.content').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="text_div">This is barbel</div>
  <p class="tag_p">That is barbel again</p>
  <div class="text_div">Some some</div>
</div>
```